# Accessing data with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have some issue on accessing data in laravel. Maybe it's just my lack of knowledge of advanced programming.

When i use  `$variable=DB::table('')->lists('id');` I get an array of data which i can access with `$variable[0]`
When i use ->get() I get a class of data?
When i use ->get(array()) I get an array of object?

Why to access this data i need to do use a foreach?
I can't access this data with `$variable->field`? When i try to access data i fetch with get() or get(array()) in that way i need always to use a foreach, i can't access data singulary even if it has just one field.

EDIT
1)

```
$nomecampo=DB::table('campo_nome')->join('lingua', 'campo_nome.id_lingua', '=', 'lingua.id') ->where('lingua.lingua','=',$lingua)->where('campo_nome.id_campo','=',$camps)->get(array('campo_nome.nome'));
eturn View::make('categorie')->with('nomecampo',$nomecampo);
```

2)

```
$nomecampo=DB::table('campo_nome')->join('lingua', 'campo_nome.id_lingua', '=', 'lingua.id') ->where('lingua.lingua','=',$lingua)->where('campo_nome.id_campo','=',$camps)->get();
eturn View::make('categorie')->with('nomecampo',$nomecampo);
```

I can't understand when to use 1 or 2 and how to access single data.

I can't access as $nomecampo->field, i mean, is just 1 field what i fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$nomecampo = DB::table('campo_nome')
               ->join('lingua', 'campo_nome.id_lingua', '=', 'lingua.id')
               ->where('lingua.lingua','=',$lingua)
               ->where('campo_nome.id_campo','=',$camps)
               ->get(array('campo_nome.nome'));
```

Replace that with `pluck('campo_nome.name')` instead of `get` to only obtain that value.

`pluck` just gets one field value, so there is no reason to use `get`, nor `first`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because get() returns a collection, 
while-as first() returns the first record 
which you can then acces the way you want.

So if you want to be able to itterate it, 
make sure you use first to return just one
record, where as get() always returns
collection. toArray converts a collection
into an array.

Comment: But i can't do like get $variable->field(1) like array

Comment: Yeah you can... use get()->toArray() and it will be an array, but why would you, as collection has a bunch of functionality too. Anyway, if you use just get your are returning a collection and you will have to itterate it by using foreach.

So long story short....

get = collection
first = just one record
toArray = converts it to an array

Comment: well because i have a lot of item that i need to place in my webpage that is just 1 string and just in that specific position, so Iwas asking myself, why i need a loop to achieve this

Comment: if i use get()->toArray i get Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object

Comment: can you paste the complete line of code ? Because on a non-object means there is no data to process. To answer your why question, that is because get returns a collection, and first just returns one record, so you have to pick the one that suits you. However when you use get then it is a collection and you have to foreach through it, why, because that is how laravel works. So without seeing any other code it is hard to be able to help you with your issue. Maybe you have no choice, maybe you can change it to get just one record, but wihtout some extra code i cannot answer that question.

Comment: i edit, thank you for your patience, but i come from php and mysql query

Comment: Actually my problem is because i need to fetch 2 name from 2 separate table and put 1 near another, so i thought i needed 2 foreach nested to achieve this, like"field1, field2" Each one comes from different query.

Comment: It becomes more an more clear now, but no you probably do not need two foreach constructions for what you want. But still we need to get more information before we can actually help you with your problem. So paste the queries you do at first, and let us see what you are exactly doing there.